# how to delete a json array itself?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to preview images when button is clicked. Problem occuring is that when i click the first image it displays and then when i click the second image,both the images together are displayed.How can i display just one image at a time? Here is my jquery code,

```
function Preview(id)
{
 $("#Preview_modal").modal("show");
    $.post("readUserDetails.php", {
        id: id              
    },
     function (data, status) {  
     var user1 = JSON.parse(data);      
     $("#element").append($("<img />").attr('src', 'data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,' + user1.image));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), `append` will add another element to the container. Use [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) instead, this will replace the existing content by the new one.

```
$("#element").html(
    $("<img />").attr('src', 'data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,' + user1.image)
);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, please select this as the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are always appending to the element:

Try to empty it first:

```
$("#element").empty().append($("<img />").attr('src', 'data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,' + user1.image));
```